# Instagram api not returning any followers although response code is 200

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I am using instagram to recieve the list of people i follow and although api returns the status code 200 I  recieve absolutely no data.I tried using postman client instead of my code and even from there no data is being returned I am hitting the following service.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=token

one thing to be noted is my application is in sandbox mode and this same access token is working and fetching  other information about the user including media shared by the user and its basic information etc and user follows and is followed by several users.

Please suggest the solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I may have answer to this question since I was facing the same issue on my WinRT project yesterday.

You may need the relationship scope instead of 'follower_list' scope.

I am assuming that you have provided the scope as 'follower_list' in the authorization URL and logged in as yourself or through your own Instagram account(the same account with which you have created your Instagram app). And now if you are hitting the above service it will return nothing in data since you are requesting if the user is following you or not(so obviously you are not following yourself)!! So if you try logging in with someone else's Instagram account and hit the above service with follower_list scope it will return **your** Instagram account in data if the logged in person is following you.

**EDIT**

The above service will return all the users that are following you **AND** present in your sandbox users list. (Or at least that is my conclusion on this)

For further clarification try https://apigee.com/console/instagram for hitting this service there they are using the relationship scope.